# Definitive way to do rounded corners inside UITableViewCells?

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, rounded-corners

So I've been all over the web, trying to figure out a definitive way to do this, and I can't seem to get it. Each of my table view cells has 3 dynamically-loaded images that I need to add rounded corners to. Right now I'm using Quartz and the `layer.cornerRadius` property of the ImageViews to round the corners, but of course it kills the scrolling performance of the table view.

Browsing online, I can't seem to find an answer to the performance problems. Most threads either end in suggesting the use of pre-rendered static images (not an option for me since the images are loaded dynamically, from the web) or some drawing trick that Loren Brichter came up with for Tweetie- however, the example project he posted on his blog is now a dead link, and I can't find it anywhere.

So basically, my question is how exactly should I go about accomplishing the rounded corners on elements inside a table view cell, without sacrificing performance? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `layer.cornerRadius` shouldn't be killing your performance. When are you setting it?

Comment: Your code has a custom UITableViewCell right? re-using your cells should allow you to keep a good performance. Also, are you loading your images in another thread? or how are you doing that? Good Luck pal!

Comment: Tommy- setting it in the init method of the custom cell class.

El Developer- Yep, custom cell. And I am reusing them, with the correct reuse identifier. For the images, I haven't even tried with the actual remote images yet, right now I'm just testing with local images.

Comment: Agree with @blabus. Adding cornerRadius to the layer just kills the smooth scrolling. It is more evident on retina display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the other answers it looks like you are using a lot of alpha transparency that is going to cost you a lot performance wise.  You may consider revisiting that to get additional frames.  One idea you may try doing is rendering the rounded image in a graphics context and using that as your cell image instead of the QuartzCore rounding.

1. Load the image in the imageview
2. Round the corners
3. Render the image into a graphics context
4. Set the imageview with the new image
5. Turn rounding off

Do all of this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  There may be more efficiencies to be had (like caching the rendered image), but this is a way to at least test out the performance of a pre-rendered rounded image.

Comment: Awesome, that sounds promising. Would you happen to have any links to code examples related to this? (specifically the part about rendering the image into a graphics context) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using a mask concept, and overlaying a mask UIImageView with transparent background over your dynamic images. Havent tried that, my self but it's an option.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that either, as the table view itself is over a textured background, which the table view scrolls independently from.